# ComboBox Datasource with CDI inside a FormLayout

Tags: vaadin, cdi, vaadin7

I use Vaadin7.3 and CDI Addon which connects my Vaadin application with my EJB Backend. My EJB Backend has a DAO for reading all entities from database.

- *MyAppUI* - Handles the base template, navigation ...
- *MyWindow* - just a modal window which shows up if i press a button on the *MyAppUI* and shows an instance of *MyForm*
- *MyForm* - declares the Form for an entity of my application

*MyAppUI* and *MyWindow* are managed through the CDI Addon and allows me to inject the DAO of the EJB Backend but *MyForm* is just an subclass of FormLayout and not managed by CDI. The Form contains a ComboBox which should show all data accessible with the DAO. How can i inject my DAO inside *MyForm*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities.

1. Don't create `MyForm` yourself but inject with @Inject. Then you can inject the DAO in `MyForm`. For this you might need to change the constructor of `MyForm` or convert the constructor to a @PostConstruct annotated method and use an empty constructor. If useful you can annotate `MyForm` with @UIScoped.
2. Pass the DAO to the constructor of `MyForm`, or if only needed later to some function (setter).
3. Define `MyForm` as non-static class inside MyWindow and use the DAO injected to MyWindow.
4. Add the DAO tho the `VaadinSession` and get it again in `MyForm`

I guess there are even more possibilities, but these are the ones that came to my mind within some seconds. I think that 1. is the cleanest and most extendable way.